# Dark screen after clicking in notification

Tags: bug, android-app

Always when I get a notification from the android app and click on it, I see the attached screenshot. An almost dark screen. I can click on the left bar and use the app, by it looks like I've missed the notification.

My phone is a Moto E 2nd generation with android 5.0.2

[image: dark screen]

Comment: No, that grey bar is the notifications pane. That's where the notifications appear - it can take a while for them to load however.

Comment: Also, your battery will need a top-up soon.

Comment: There's a dupe on [meta.se] (sorry, on mobile, hard to browse for cross-site dupe). It's a known issue on this version of the app.

Comment: I have let it open for a long time and the screen didn't update